# Unable to select calendar dates from drop down "Date selector"(YYYY/MM/DD) in Selenium VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Trying to automate a website, where-in i'm finding difficulty in selecting the date from drop down list. 
This is the website : **https://www.icegate.gov.in/DocEnquiry/iecEnq/IECSB**

I have an excel file with IEC code, PAN number, Start Date and End Date.
First 2 part i can finish up, but while selecting dates i'm finding difficulty.

**IEC no.**

1. 0907012248
2. 0906018463

**PAN no.**

1. AAFCA2804G
2. AAGCA0259A

**Start Dates - Any 30 days frame.(lets say 2020/01/01 To 2020/01/31)**

```
Sub MEISsite()

Dim bot As WebDriver
Dim count As Long

Set bot = New WebDriver
bot.Start "Chrome"
count = 1

While (Len(Range("A" & count)) > 0)

bot.Get "https://www.icegate.gov.in/DocEnquiry/iecEnq/IECSB"

bot.FindElementByXPath("//input[@id='iecNo']").SendKeys Range("A" & count)
bot.FindElementByXPath("//input[@id='panNo']").SendKeys Range("B" & count)


'Below part is where the Drop down list Date selector is causing me problem.

bot.FindElementByXPath("//tr[4]/td[2]/img[1]").Click
bot.FindElementByXPath("//select[@name='calendar-month']").SendKeys Range("C" & count)
bot.FindElementByXPath("//select[@name='calendar-year']").SendKeys Range("D" & count)

bot.FindElementByXPath("//tr[5]/td[2]/img[1]").Click
bot.FindElementByXPath("//select[@name='calendar-month']").SendKeys Range("C" & count)
bot.FindElementByXPath("//select[@name='calendar-year']").SendKeys Range("D" & count)


'bot.Wait 10000
bot.FindElementByXPath("//span[@id='iecSBEnq']").Click

Range("I" & count) = bot.FindElementByXPath("//table[@id='resultTable']").Text

'bot.Wait 1000
End If
End If
count = count + 1
Wend
bot.Quit
End Sub
```

I divided the year,month and dates into separate columns in excel to try it out, but all this code is able to do is click on the drop down list of date selector(that's all).

Please help me out.

Comment: @QHarr 
Any tips ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a better approach but this is what I tried and it is OK for me

```
Sub MEISsite()
Dim e, bot As WebDriver, ele As SelectElement, eledpTD As Object, r As Long, i As Long

Set bot = New WebDriver
r = 1

With bot
    .Start "Chrome"

    While (Len(Range("A" & r)) > 0)
        .Get "https://www.icegate.gov.in/DocEnquiry/iecEnq/IECSB"

        .FindElementByXPath("//input[@id='iecNo']").SendKeys Range("A" & r)
        .FindElementByXPath("//input[@id='panNo']").SendKeys Range("B" & r)

        For i = 1 To 2
            With .FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='pagetable']/tbody/tr[" & i + 3 & "]/td[2]")
                .ScrollIntoView: .Click
            End With
            Set ele = .FindElementByName("calendar-month").AsSelect
            ele.SelectByIndex Month(Cells(r, i + 2)) - 1
            Set ele = .FindElementByName("calendar-year").AsSelect
            ele.SelectByValue CStr(Year(Cells(r, i + 2)))
            Set eledpTD = .FindElementsByClass("dpTD")
            For Each e In eledpTD
                If Val(e.Text) = Val(Day(Cells(r, i + 2))) Then
                    e.Click: Exit For
                End If
            Next e
        Next i

        r = r + 1
    Wend

    Stop
    .Quit
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: How are you selecting the dates ???
You want the dates to be selected as we put in excel cells like.  YYYY/MM/DD or
else bifurcation is needed among different cells ?
Because dates are provided in excel sheet and we need to enter according to that.

Comment: How is the format of the dates in your worksheet? .. The code is working fine for me.

Comment: Thank you Yasser, i got the dates to run.
Bbut when i try to add a statement to extract the table in result table, it comes out of loop.

Comment: You should put the rest of the code before the end of the loop and put some waiting lines

Comment: Thanks la ot Yasser Sir.
Total Life saver.